# Making Vectors as Different As Possible

Tags: linear-algebra, machine-learning

I am given a function $f:\mathbb{R}^M\times\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^K$.  Let us denote the inputs to $f$ as $(a,b)$, where $a\in\mathbb{R}^M$ and $b\in\mathbb{R}^N$  The set of possible values of $b$ is finite (that is, there is a finite number of vectors $b$ that I care about).

Consider a function $g_a:\mathbb{R}^N\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^K$ where $g_a(b)=f(a,b)$ for a specific $a$.  My goal is to find the value of $a$ so that the vectors that are output from $g_a$ are as different as possible from each other in the sense that the angle between any two vectors is as large as possible.

Consider the matrix $\Gamma(a)$ where each column of $\Gamma(a)$ is an output of $g$.  I think that the singular values of $\Gamma(a)$ are relevant.  For example, I could choose the values of $a$ that maximize the volume of the ellipsoid that is the image of the unit ball under $\Gamma$.  Or, I could choose the values of $a$ that maximize the smallest singular value of $\Gamma$.

What is the best metric to use in this situation?  I would guess that there already exists some theory that's relevant to my problem.  Could someone provide me with a specific reference?  My own searches have not been fruitful.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you thought of this, but an obvious idea is to literally use the sum of angles between the vectors:
$$
E(a) = \sum_{b\in B} \sum_{\beta\in B} 
\arccos\left(
\frac{g_a(b)^Tg_a(\beta)}{||g_a(b)||_2\;||g_a(\beta)||_2}
\right)
$$
where $B\subset \mathbb{R}^N$.
Then use e.g. gradient descent on $E$ to optimize it.

As for your $\Gamma$ idea, one idea is to use the covariance matrix of the data; i.e. consider the set of output vectors as being drawn from a multivariate probability distribution and try to maximize the (estimated) variance of this distribution. This will try to "spread out" the points as much as possible, in a certain sense.

However, there are many ways to do this. Read [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225434/a-measure-of-variance-from-the-covariance-matrix), [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99560/generalization-of-variance-to-random-vectors?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72228/measures-of-multidimensional-spread-or-variance?noredirect=1&lq=1), for instance.
So for some variance measure $V_j$, we will want $a = \arg\max_{a\in \mathbb{R}^M} V_j$.

Let $M_a=\Gamma(a)^T - \mu_{a}$, where $\mu_a$ is the matrix of column means of $\Gamma(a)^T$. Then let:
$$
C_a = \frac{1}{|B|-1}M_a^TM_a
$$
be the centered covariance matrix. Note that I'm assuming you're working over all $B$ (your finite set), but you obviously don't have to :).

Then, one measure is the total component-wise variance is given by:
$$
V_1 = \text{tr}(C_a) = \sum_i \lambda_i(C_a)
$$
where $\lambda_i(A)$ is the $i$th eigenvalue of $A$.
Another measure is:
$$
V_2 = \sqrt{\det(C_a)} = \sqrt{\prod_i^{\,} \lambda_i(C_a)}
$$
which is the product of the component variances.

However, you might want to have a little more isometry; i.e. reduce the covariances, while still increasing the variances.
(See [here](http://www.visiondummy.com/2014/04/geometric-interpretation-covariance-matrix/) for some visualization).

A simple method is just to use:
$$
V_3 = \text{tr}({C_a}) - \frac{1}{K-1}\sum_i (\lambda_i(C_a) - \mu_\lambda)^2
$$
where the extra term is the estimate of $\mathbb{V}[\lambda]$ with $\mu_\lambda = \frac{1}{K}\sum_j \lambda_j(C_a)$.

For a more physics flavour, use the notion of a deviator tensor (e.g. see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_stress_tensor#Stress_deviator_tensor)), which measures the "non-isometric" component of a tensor.
Let:
$$
\Psi = C_a - \frac{\text{tr}({C_a})}{K}I
$$
Then consider:
$$
V_4 = \text{tr}({C_a}) - ||\Psi||
$$
where $||\Psi||$ could be the spectral 2-norm or the Frobenius norm for instance.

Comment: Thank you for this insight!  I tried V1, but there's an issue.  Since the sum is getting maximized, the optimization makes the first singular value very large and the rest very small.  It seems like, if it could, it would make the first singular value as large as possible and the rest 0.  This would yield a set of angles between vectors of 0 (or pi).  What I would prefer is something where the angles between vectors are maximized.  (Do I make sense?)  Any ideas about how I could proceed?  Also, do you have a citable reference for the material presented here?

Comment: @NicNic8 If the problem is that $\lambda_1$ was too large compared to the other eigenvalues, consider using $V_3$ or $V_4$, which would penalize that. Also, is there something wrong with $E(a)$? Sorry, I made them up =/ ... everything here would be in any stats or matrix theory textbook though.