# Unidimensional variability measure for multivariate random samples (or time series)

Tags: probability, variance, time-series

I have multiple samples on $n$-dimensional random vectors (from a time-series). I'll like to have a **unidimensional measure** of its variability.

A natural one (discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/99560/generalization-of-variance-to-random-vectors)) is to extend the *variance* for n-dimensional vectors
$$ \mathbb{E}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n (X_i-\mathbb{E}(X_i))^2\right) = \sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{V}(X_i)$$
however this measure can have scale-problems, for example, if the magnitude of the values in one dimension is considerably larger than the other dimensions.

Which measures are appropriate for this case?

Comment: You may take a norm of the covariance matrix. BTW, in the time-series context, the mentioned equation need not hold.

Comment: Thanks @d.k.o..  In fact, norm(cov) gives me very similar results.  I didn't understand your last comment about time-series. Expressions is mathematically correct by linearity of the expected value. What did you try to say about time-series?

Comment: I see. Your formula is just the sum of individual variances and it disregards the covariance structure. OK then.